# How to use a Spring RemoteExporter with @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an (RPC) service which I'm exposing using `RemoteExporter` like below:

```java
@Service
public class FooService {
  // some operations here
}

@Configuration
public class RpcConfiguration {
  @Bean("/foo.rpc")
  RemoteExporter fooService(FooService foo) {
    // create and return the exporter here
  }
}
```

Everything works just fine. Now I'd like to expose the service under the path `/foo/{fooId}/bar.rpc` (instead of `/foo.rpc`). <del>I think `RemoteExporter` doesn't understand the path variable (`fooId`) which is fine, as long as I can expose it under the path `/foo/*/bar.rpc` (I'll extract the path variable in the exporter myself).</del>
Is there a way to do it in Spring (Boot), preferably without XML stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be way smarter than I thought. Just use the pattern given in the question as the bean name! ‍♂️